# Problem in importing Paramiko in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, paramiko, pysftp

I am trying to import paramiko library to AWS Lambda. I have tried to do so on lambda using Python version 2.7, 3.6, 3.8. I upload the zip file (created on ec2 machine using cmd, containing all dependencies) by creating a layer on Lambda function, however it keeps giving me the error-No module named Paramiko. Could you please suggest me how to successfully import paramiko to establish an sftp connection.

Answer (score 1):

I have imported paramiko to Lambda Python 3.8 runtime as a layer.  The point is you have to pip install it and pack it into a zip file in amznlinux2 x86 EC2 instance with Python3.8 installed. And make sure all content in the zip file is in a folder named python.